Unable to get shared clipboard using VNC server on Ubuntu and Mac client
I have a remote Oracle Cloud VM running Ubuntu, and I want to remote in via VNC via macos Screen Sharing. I can connect with Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10 – but for the life of me cannot get shared clipboard to work.
This is my xstartup
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
export DISPLAY=:1
eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &
vncconfig -nowin &
mate-session &
gnome-terminal &
chromium-browser &

